# pyqtgraph examples TableWidget throws a TypeError when trying to save data in a tab seperated file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am running TableWidget example in pyqtgraph 0.10.0 on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine on python 3.6.4.

```
from pyqtgraph import examples
examples.run()
```

Then choose TableWidget example under Widgets and click Run Examples.

When I try to save the TableWidget data in a local tsv by right clicking on the table and selecting 'Save All' and then 'Save' after entering a filename in the file selection popup, I get the following error:

```
File "..\TableWidget.py", line 350, in save
    open(fileName, 'w').write(data)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

I can not seem to find anything in the issues on their repository on GitHub. Does anyone else has similar issues?

Comment: what is `data`?

Comment: so I run pyqtgraph.examples.run() and choose TableWidget examples. I am thinking it's the default data in the TableWidget. I am not changing anything. If I right click on the table and choose 'Save Selection' or 'Save All' and click save after entering the filename in a popup dialog, I get the aforementioned error. I get the same error when I click cancel in the file selection popup.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: What type is fileName?

Comment: I edited my question so that one can exactly follow what I am trying to do.

Comment: Where you are saving the file?, I get that error if I save it in a place that I do not have permission to write, but if I save it in Desktop or Documents it is saved normally.

Comment: Jack, I do not know. This is the source code and examples that come with it that I am talking about. I tried to reproduce the issue using my own app and facing the same problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc, good point. I tried saving it in a few different locations on my PC but getting the same error.

Comment: @Floydian. This is caused by a bug in pyqtgraph. The [example calls `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()`](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/widgets/TableWidget.py#L346) and assumes the return value will be a single string (i.e. the filename). This is correct for pyqt4, but not for pyqt5, where the return value is a tuple of the filename and the selected filter.